# Is it possible to perform some action BEFORE a JFrame is minimized?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, frame

In Swing, there are several ways to capture the event of minimizing a frame (iconifying), but the event happens when the frame is ICONIFIED which means after the frame becomes invisible from the screen.

Now I wish to run some code **before** disappearance of the frame -- **immediately when I click the taskbar button**.

In other words, **do something when the JFrame is "about to" (NOT AFTER) be minimized**. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I'm (very) late but if nothing else works and this is important, I would go for an undecorated frame with custom minimize/maximize/etc. buttons.
Btw, did you try to override the look & feel (I guess it's responsible for drawing those buttons) and use your own processing there?

Comment: I am working on the undecorated frame solution right now as it seems the only feasible route, however the Look & Feel idea is an interesting route which I will explore this weekend. If you can throw one or more samples together into a usable answer, I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WindowStateListener`, and call `WindowEvent#getNewState()` and check against `Frame.ICONIFIED`.

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        };

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent we) {
                if (we.getNewState() == Frame.ICONIFIED) {
                    System.out.println("Here");
                }
            }
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It also works fine on Windows, but that event is still caught after the window is minimized. I would say sorry that my question may not be so understandable, but what I try to emphasis is can I catch something when the window is "about to be minimized"?

Comment: Even changing the position of super.windowStateChanged(we) and my code, it is still caught when the window is already "ICONIFIED", what I want here is "ICONIFYING" -- like "WINDOW_CLOSING".

Comment: @shuangwhywhy Oh I see, no I dont think thats possible.

Comment: @David, thank you for your help. In fact, I just want to make some custom window animations when minimizing, deiconifying, and closing. For closing and deiconifying are both easy to achieve so, I'm just stuck on that "minimizing" stuff. Thank you anyway and it seems I have to give it up.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `JFrame` and override `setExtendedState` method.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

   ....
    setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED); 
   ....


@Override
public void setExtendedState(int state) {       
    // your code

    super.setExtendedState(state);
   };

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim, I have overridden this method as well as setState() but when I click the taskbar button, the frame just disappears and nothing happens.

Comment: @David, Thank you but I'm afraid neither setState() nor setExtendedState() is called when the frame is iconified by the system? -- This is the problem, actually, I undecorated the JFrame and attached my own custom minimize button which calls setState() and it works fine in this way, but if I click in the taskbar to minimize it, it's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question "Is it possible to perform some action BEFORE a JFrame is minimized?"

I would say no unfortunately, I checked the native code for openjdk (windows) for [frame](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/jdk/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Frame.cpp) and [window](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/jdk/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Window.cpp) that sends these events to java-space. And as I understand it, it is a callback from the windows API [VM_SIZE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646(v=vs.85).aspx). And the `SIZE_MINIMIZED` is sent when "The window has been minimized" and is not getting any messages before the actual minimization.